# Does Groovy have method to merge 2 maps?

Tags: dictionary, groovy

First map is default options `[a: true, b: false]`. Second map - options passed by user `[a:false]`. Does Groovy has maps merge method to obtain `[a: false, b:false]`?

It's not problem to implement it in Groovy. I'm asking about method out of the box

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You can use plus:

```
assert [ a: true, b: false ] + [ a: false ] == [ a: false, b: false ]
```

Or left shift:

```
assert [ a: true, b: false ] << [ a: false ] == [ a: false, b: false ]
```

The difference is that `<<` [adds the right hand map into the left hand map](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L12296).  When you use `+`, it [constructs a new Map based on the LHS](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L7433), and adds the right hand map into it

Comment: Also maybe worth noting that when you can use `+`, you can also use `+=`: `def m1 =[ a: true, b: false ]; m1 += [ a: false ] ; println (m1 == [ a: false, b: false ])`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use [**`Map.withDefault(Closure)`**](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#withDefault(groovy.lang.Closure)) Groovy Enhancement method or the [**Spread operator (`*`)**](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_map_elements), besides using the [plus (`+`)](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#plus(java.util.Map)) and [left shift (`<<`)](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#leftShift(java.util.Map)) operators:

#### `Map.withDefault(Closure init)`

```
def defaults = [ a: true, b: false, ]
def args = [ a: false, ]
def options = args.withDefault { defaults[it] }

assert options == [ a: false ]
assert [ options["a"], options["b"] ] == [ false, false ]
assert options == [ a: false, b: false ]
```

> `Map.withDefault` wraps a map using the decorator pattern with a wrapper that intercepts
> all calls to `get(key)`. If an unknown key is found, a default value
> will be stored into the Map before being returned. The default value
> stored will be the result of calling the supplied Closure with the key
> as the parameter to the Closure.

If you have a requirement that every boolean in the Map has the same value by default, then you could write the following:

```
def args = [ a: true, ]
def options = args.withDefault { false }

assert options == [ a: true ]
assert [ options["a"], options["b"], options["c"] ] == [ true, false, false ]
assert options == [ a: true, b: false, c: false ]
```

#### Spread Operator (`*`)

```
def defaults = [ a: true, b: false, ]
def args = [ a: false, ]

assert [ foo: "bar", *: defaults, *: args, ] == [ a: false, b: false, foo: "bar" ]
```

> Roughly similar to the plus operator but works only on map literals.

#### Plus Operator (`+`)

```
assert [ a: true, b: false ] + [ a: false ] == [ a: false, b: false ]
```

> Roughly equivalent to `Map m = new HashMap(); m.putAll(left); m.putAll(right); return m;`.

#### Left Shift Operator (`<<`)

```
assert [ a: true, b: false ] << [ a: false ] == [ a: false, b: false ]
```

> Roughly equivalent to `left.putAll(right); return left;`.

---

Also, you could get the default value by demand in a wrapper function similar to what `Map.withDefault` does:

#### Map.get(Object key, Object defaultValue)

```
def defaults = [ a: true, b: false, ]
def args = [ a: false, ]
assert args.get("a", defaults["a"]) == false
assert args.get("b", defaults["b"]) == false
```

For a method which doesn't mutate the map, consider instead using [Map#getOrDefault(Object, Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) or consider using Groovy's MapWithDefault.

- <sub>Plus and Shift operator sections were inspired by Tim Yates' answer.</sub>
- <sub>Checkout Groovy's Enhancement [Map](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html) documentation for better understanding.</sub>