# how to join list of maps in groovy

Tags: groovy

If i have two list of maps in groovy...

```
def x = [ [a:1, b:2], [a:1, b:3], [a:2, b:4] ]
​def y = ​[ [f:10, b:2, g:7], [f:100, b:3, g:8], [f:20, b:4, g:9] ]
```

How can I join them based on a particular attribute. In the above example the values for `b`.

Desired result is...

```
[a:1, b:2, f:10, g:7]
[a:1, b:3, f:100, g:8]
[a:2, b:4, f:20, g:9]
```

I tried this but it's not exactly what I'm after.

```
def z = (x + y).groupBy { it.b }
z.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two maps in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267591/how-to-merge-two-maps-in-groovy)

Comment: Richie, check the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
[x,y].transpose().collect { a, b -> a + b }
```

Comment: This variant returns this:
[[a:1, b:3], [a:2, b:4], [f:20, b:4, g:9]] instead of [[a:1, b:2, f:10, g:7], [a:1, b:3, f:100, g:8], [a:2, b:4, f:20, g:9]]
Why dose it marked as accepted?

Comment: @Seyf no it doesn't, it returns `[[a:1, b:2, f:10, g:7], [a:1, b:3, f:100, g:8], [a:2, b:4, f:20, g:9]]`, I just checked in Groovy 3.0.9

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake :(
I am so sorry!

Comment: @Seyf no worries at all 

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the desired result with:

```
println (x + y).groupBy { it.b }.collect{it.value}.collect{item -> def m = [:] ; item.collect{ m +=it}; m }
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](http://ideone.com/putjm2)</kbd>

Comment: richie, looks you had a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905405/using-transpose-to-merge-lists-in-full-outer-join-style) for the same? But this gives the desired result. Have you checked?